# Select-Object -Unique

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, pipeline

My understanding is that

```
$list = @('1', '2', '3', '1', '4')
Select-Object -InputObject $list -Unique
```

should return an array of just 4 elements, skipping the second '1' that is not unique.

But I am getting all 5 elements back. Am I understanding this wrong, or does Select-Object have a bug, at least in the PS 5.1 that I am testing on?

Comment: `'1', '2', '3', '1', '4'|Select-Object -Unique ` works as expected though. Somehow the use of -InputObject makes it go wrong. Interesting...

Comment: Found this in the documentation: -InputObject
Specifies objects to send to the cmdlet through the pipeline. This parameter enables you to pipe objects to Select-Object.

When you pass objects to the InputObject parameter, instead of using the pipeline, Select-Object treats the InputObject as a single object, even if the value is a collection. It is recommended that you use the pipeline when passing collections to Select-Object.

Comment: @gert-jan-kraaijeveld Good find! And an interesting problem, given that I usually avoid the pipeline whenever possible because 1: Pipeline pollution is a thing, and 2: the pipeline is SLOW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **With only a few exceptions**, notably `ConvertFrom-Csv`, `Get-Random`, `Join-String`, and `Get-Member`, **the `-InputObject` parameter should be thought of as an *implementation detail* whose purpose is to *facilitate pipeline input***, and which therefore **shouldn't be used *directly***. The built-in cmdlets fall into one of the following categories:

  - **Category A**: A select few cmdlets such as `Get-Member` *usefully* distinguish between passing an input collection as an *argument* to `-InputObject` and implicitly enumerating the collection's *elements* via the pipeline.
  - **Category B**: A select few cmdlets, such as `ConvertFrom-Csv` (but *not* `ConvertTo-Csv`), `Get-Random`, `Join-String` and `Out-String`, either have *array*-valued `-InputObject` parameters  (e.g. `-InputObject <psobject[]>`) or *explicitly perform enumeration* on the argument passed to their *scalar* `InputObject` parameters (e.g., `-InputObject <psobject>`).

    - For *flat* input collections (which are typical)<sup>[1]</sup>, such cmdlets effectively treat direct argument-passing the same as pipeline input - except that direct argument-passing is *much faster*; see below.
  - **Category C**: Unfortunately, **the majority of cmdlets have scalar `-InputObject` parameters *and* process collections passed to `-InputObject` *as a whole*, which effectively makes the parameter useless for direct argument-passing**.
- This is **somewhat unfortunate**, because **passing an already in-memory collection *as an argument* to a cmdlet is much faster than sending its elements one by one through the pipeline**.

  - For instance, compare the runtime of passing 1 million items to `Get-Random` using either direct argument-passing or the pipeline: `Get-Random -InputObject (1..1e6)` vs.
    `1..1e6 | Get-Random`
  - Note that this optimization is sometimes also available for *other* cmdlet parameters; notably, you can pass a collection to `Set-Content`'s `-Value` parameter as an alternative to piping it, which greatly speeds up writing.

---

Here's a categorized and alphabetically sorted list of built-in cmdlets:

- Category A: USEFUL DISTINCTION between pipeline input and explicit `-InputObject` use: to process collections *as a whole*, pass them to `-InputObject`; to process their *elements* one by one, use the pipeline:

  - `Add-Member`
  - `Export-Clixml`
  - `Get-Member`
  - `Trace-Command`
- Category B: USEFUL EQUIVALENCE for *flat* collections: you can pass flat collections directly to `-InputObject` to speed up processing:

  - `ConvertFrom-Csv`
  - `Format-Custom`
  - `Format-List`
  - `Format-Table`
  - `Format-Wide`
  - `Get-Random`
  - `Join-String`
  - `Out-Host`
  - `Out-String`
- Category C: USELESS DISTINCTION: Direct `-InputObject` use is pointless:

  - `ConvertTo-Csv`
  - `ConvertTo-Html`
  - `ConvertTo-Xml`
  - `Export-Csv`
  - `ForEach-Object`
  - `Format-Hex`
  - `Get-Unique`
  - `Group-Object`
  - `Invoke-Command`
  - `Measure-Command`
  - `Measure-Object`
  - `Select-Object`
  - `Select-String`
  - `Sort-Object`
  - `Start-Job`
  - `Update-List`
  - `Where-Object`

---

[1] Processing differences of *nested* collections between pipeline input and `-InputObject` use:

Those cmdlets that enumerate their `-InputObject` arguments perform only *one* level of enumeration on the input collection, and leave *nested* collections as-is.

By contrast, pipeline use can result in *two* levels of iteration, as the following `Join-String` example shows:

```
PS> Join-String -InputObject ('foo', ('bar', 'baz'))
foobar baz
```

`foo` and the stringification of the nested array *as a whole* - `bar baz` - were joined.

```
PS> 'foo', ('bar', 'baz') | Join-String
foobarbaz
```

`foo` and the *enumerated elements* of the nested array were joined.

The reason is that *two* processing passes happen in this case, due to the pipeline's enumeration behavior: `foo` is passed first, followed by nested array `'bar', 'baz'`, and the single-level enumeration is performed on *each*, and the results across all input objects are joined.